# Get from a smarty variable the day of week

Tags: php, datetime, smarty

I want add condition to a variable if the day of this condition is a Monday,
Example:

```
{if $order.details.order_date == monday}
 {$order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|cat:' +8 days'|date_format:'%A, %e de %B del %Y'}
{/if}
```

How can I read from a variable if the date is a monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1:
  Also pass the calculated day of the week, along with the date, in $order.details, from PHP
- Option 2:
  Apply a filter to $order.details.order_date:

```smarty
{if $order.details.order_date|date_format:'l' == 'Monday'}
```

##### Edit: more options.

Depending on your version of Smarty you can also try:

```smarty
{if $order.details.order_date|date_format:'%u' == 1}
```

Where the result of the date_format filter is an "ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week, 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)", see  [strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) for more information

Alternatively you can also try to assign the value to a variable before testing it:

```smarty
{$dayOfWeek = {$order.details.order_date|date_format:'%u'}}
{if $dayOfWeek == 1}
```

#### Further Edit

You can try to convert the variable and then apply the filter:

```smarty
{$dateYMD = {{$order.details.order_date|substr:6:4}|cat:'-'|cat:{$order.details.order_date|substr:3:2}|cat:'-'|cat:{$order.details.order_date|substr:0:2}}}
{if $dateYMD|date_format:'%u' == 1}
```

but you could receive some 'deprecated' messages from PHP if they are not disabled, since substr will be removed in future smarty releases.

You can also try replacing the slashes with dashes, it seems to work but I do not garantee for that:

```smarty
{if $order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|date_format:'%u' == 1}
```

Comment: sorry, i checked this code in a order of a Monday but is not show nothing. How can apply a filter of weekdays to $order.details.order_date ?

Comment: You didn't say which version of Smarty you have: I tested my code with the latest one and it works. Note that $order.details.order_date must be a valid date.
I add more options to my answer.

Comment: my smarty version is 4.2.1 (prestashop with php 8.2). I tried with your codes and changin the "1" for "5" for a order hired the friday but is not working. Only works your code if I add "3", it seem it detect "3" as friday. Note that the simple variable {$order.details.order_date} detect date in format 04/08/2023

Comment: Dates must be in %Y-%m-%d (2023-08-04) format, *"04/08/2023"* is not a good date format and it's value is misinterpreted. To verify this you can try: `{$date1 = '2023-08-04'} {$date1} - {$date1|date_format:'%u'}` and then 
`{$date2 = '04/08/2023'} {$date2} - {$date2|date_format:'%u'}` to see the difference

Comment: variable date {$order.details.order_date} is of prestashop, i can´t modify it.
First code test 2023-08-04 5 (Ok, the 5 is friday).
Second code test 04/08/2023 6 (Ok, the 6 is saturday). It read the week day; How can I read the week day of variable {$order.details.order_date} ?

Comment: I added more information to my answer

Comment: your code {if $order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|date_format:'%u' == 1} worked, the error is prestashop have "/" in dates, i changed it per "-" and just now I finished my codes :D thank you so much